# What is the use of opencv library in android

Tags: android, opencv

I have tried to read about opencv library library and it has something to do with our eye reading but i am not able to get what exactly are its true capabilities.

All the tutorials i got on net started implemented this library but couldn't find any explaining why it is used. So anyone please explain me

Comment: Wikipedia has a good explanation of the library: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opencv

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is a computer vision library that has many real world uses.

such as: Human-Computer interaction, object identification, segmentation and recognition, face recognition, gesture recognition, motion tracking, motion understanding, stereo and multi-camera calibration, depth computation and mobile robotics.

(All of this is written in the opencv tag you used in your question by the way)

I think you probably could have gotten all this information from a quick google search however. Perhaps next time, just do that?

Comment: read this in tag. didn't  understood still.

Comment: It's a way of making your computer (or android device) understand what it can see through its camera. If you were to see a dog walking down the street, your eyes don't know that it's a dog, but your brain does. It's like giving the camera on your phone a brain.